# How to interpret relative stopping tolerance for optimization?

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm spinning up on both integer linear programming and Matlab's [Problem-Based Workflow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/problem-based-workflow.html).  The Mixed Integer Linear Program (MILP) [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/mixed-integer-linear-programming-basics-problem-based.html), ends with references to [stopping tolerances](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/tolerances-and-stopping-criteria.html):

> `StepTolerance` is generally used as a *relative* bound, meaning
>   iterations end when $|(x_i – x_{i+1})| < `StepTolerance`*(1 +
>   |x_i|)$, or a similar relative measure

I would have expected a relative tolerance to be used in a manner similar to one of the following:

- | x_i - x_{i+1} | < `StepTolerance` |x_i|
- | x_i - x_{i+1} | < `StepTolerance` | x_i + x_{i+1} |
- | x_i - x_{i+1} | < `StepTolerance` | x_i + x_{i+1} | / 2

Can anyone please explain how the documented behaviour is "relative"?

For me, the same question applies to the (apparently relative) objective `FunctionTolerance` immediately following the `StepTolerance` section of the aforementioned [stopping tolerances](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/tolerances-and-stopping-criteria.html) page.

Thanks.

**Additional context**

The cited MILP example ends in a Matlab message about gap tolerance, which pops up a help box when clicked. In turn, the help box links to the aforementioned stopping tolerances page. It is possible that the stopping tolerances page was too general a reference for the MILP example, and I'll mention this in the original post. However, I'm still curious about how to interpret the relativeness of the tolerance in the more general sense, e.g., say, in a gradient descent context.

Comment: Your first example is identical to what's in the documentation except for the `1+` in the right-hand side. The `1+` is probably there to handle situations in which |x_i|=0, in which case the < would never hold.

Comment: 1 seems like a kind of large constant to use there. For example, CPLEX uses 1.0e-10 for their relative MIP gap termination criterion: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpGap.html

Comment: I currently do not see the `1+` as a fudging of my first example, simply because the scale of the steps (and of `x`) is unknown.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but the gap-tolerance / mip-gap in MIPs has nothing to do with first-order-optimization like tolerances about two consecutive iterations. I would be careful about mixing all those different optimization technologies and problems (discrete vs. continuous; LP vs. NLP; combinatoric-like (Simplex) vs. analytical (Interior-point) and so on)

Comment: The cited MILP example ends in a Matlab message about gap tolerance, which pops up a help box when clicked. In turn, the help box links to the aforementioned `stopping tolerances` page.  It is possible that the `stopping tolerances` page was too general a reference for the MILP example, and I'll mention this in the original post.  However, I'm still curious about how to interpret the relativeness of the tolerance in the more general sense, e.g., say, in a gradient descent context.

Comment: I don't think that `intlinprog` takes into account `StepTolerance`.  The stopping criterion that is referred to in the example you linked above is the `RelativeGapTolerance`, see [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html).  Note that there is an absolute counterpart `AbsoluteGapTolerance`, too.

Comment: @sascha My comment wasn't meant to suggest that MATLAB's `StepTolerance` and CPLEX's `relmipgap` are equivalent, only that it's common practice to add a positive constant to the denominator when calculating relative measures that are then compared to a tolerance.

Comment: @Robert: Understood that the stopping tolerances page might be too general a reference for intlinprog (used in the MILP example), but I still have the question of how the documented expressions can be considered "relative" even in a more general optimal search, e.g., gradient descent.